# exponent of automorphisms

Tags: group-theory

We know that  $\left\vert G\right\vert <\infty \Rightarrow \left\vert Aut\left( G\right)
\right\vert <\infty $.

My question is: $\exp \left( G\right) <\infty \Rightarrow \exp \left( Aut\left( G\right)
\right) <\infty ?$

Where $Aut\left( G\right) $=set automorphisms of $G$ and $\exp \left( G\right)$ is the exponent of G.

Comment: What is meant by $\mbox{exp}(G)$?

Comment: The exponent of G.

Comment: Next question: what if $G$ is finitely generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $G$ be the product of infinitely many copies of $C_2$. Then $\text{Aut}(G)$ contains permutations of infinite order.

Comment: You could show it to me?

Comment: For example let the indexing set be $\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the permutation $n \mapsto n + 1$.